# Why is an attribute for my object showing two different values in my console ? Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my User model that is appropriate:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110412170916
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                   :integer         not null, primary key
#  email                :string(255)
#  encrypted_password   :string(128)
#  password_salt        :string(255)
#  reset_password_token :string(255)
#  remember_token       :string(255)
#  remember_created_at  :datetime
#  sign_in_count        :integer
#  current_sign_in_at   :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at      :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip   :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip      :string(255)
#  username             :string(255)
#  first_name           :string(255)
#  last_name            :string(255)
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  invitation_token     :string(60)
#  invitation_sent_at   :datetime
#  plan_id              :integer
#  current_state        :string(255)
#  confirmation_token   :string(255)
#  confirmed_at         :datetime
#  confirmation_sent_at :datetime
#  space_used           :integer         default(0), not null
#  failed_attempts      :integer         default(0)
#  unlock_token         :string(255)
#  locked_at            :datetime
#  trial_end_date       :date
#  active_subscription  :boolean
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_trial_end

  def set_trial_end
    plan = Plan.find(plan_id)
    end_of_trial = self.created_at + plan.trial_duration.days
    self.trial_end_date = end_of_trial
  end

end
```

When I created a user at the console, and saved it, it shows the right entry. Specifically the `trial_end_date` is correct for the first one....i.e. the variable `admin` as seen below:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > admin.save
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > admin
 => #<User id: 19, email: "test13@abc.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$W0eMZ8mrRw85/bM0eYjkc.DimnMj4awD1VdkqfuQe4JZ...", password_salt: "$2a$10$W0eMZ8mrRw85/bM0eYjkc.", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: nil, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, username: "test13", first_name: "Test", last_name: "Thirteen", created_at: "2011-04-17 22:20:08", updated_at: "2011-04-17 22:20:08", invitation_token: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, plan_id: 4, current_state: nil, confirmation_token: "TqlstUs_YuOzZ8OTAZmx", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2011-04-17 22:20:08", space_used: 0, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, trial_end_date: "2011-04-24 22:20:08", active_subscription: nil>
```

But once I do `User.last` this is what I see, and `user.trial_end_date` is set to `nil`.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > User.last
 => #<User id: 19, email: "test13@abc.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$W0eMZ8mrRw85/bM0eYjkc.DimnMj4awD1VdkqfuQe4JZ...", password_salt: "$2a$10$W0eMZ8mrRw85/bM0eYjkc.", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: nil, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, username: "test13", first_name: "Test", last_name: "Thirteen", created_at: "2011-04-17 22:20:08", updated_at: "2011-04-17 22:20:08", invitation_token: nil, invitation_sent_at: nil, plan_id: 4, current_state: nil, confirmation_token: "TqlstUs_YuOzZ8OTAZmx", confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: "2011-04-17 22:20:08", space_used: 0, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, trial_end_date: nil, active_subscription: nil>
```

Why does `trial_end_date` save it as `nil` for the actual User object and not in the variable ?

Comment: should that be self.plan_id instead of just plan_id in the before_save?

Comment: That does the same thing. But as I understood it, it doesn't matter. I am pretty sure I tried that and the result was the same. Will do it again and confirm.

Comment: also, you might want before_create rather than before_save

Comment: is correct "plan_id" is the EXACT same as "self.plan_id" unless plan_id was previously a left side argument in the same variable scope.

Comment: Paul, I tried every permutation of before_save, before_create & all the afters. Nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `created_at` in a `before` callback because it won't be set. Use `Time.now` or `Date.today`.

Answer (score 2):

Your database record wants type Date, not DateTime.

In similar situations, I'm careful to set the AR var to be a Date.

Other people have had the same problem. See Ruby forum [msg](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1200360)

Re: Why do the Inspections of the AR instances "admin" and User.last differ? Because "admin" is the data that you want saved to the dbms. User.last is an entirely new instance of an AR record that has been populated with data *from* the dbms.

**Suggested Solution**

Change

```
def set_trial_end
  plan = Plan.find(plan_id)
  end_of_trial = self.created_at + plan.trial_duration.days
  self.trial_end_date = end_of_trial.to_date ### explicitly convert to date
end
```

Comment: This looks like it explains it, but this is the error I now get: `NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+`

It says the error is around this line `end_of_trial = self.created_at + plan.trial_duration.days`

Comment: Ok I changed `self.created_at` to `Date.today` so the line reads: `end_of_trial = Date.today + plan.trial_duration.days`. However, it is still saving it as nil.

Comment: what type is trial_duration? You should just be adding a simple integer to Date.today. Not a day's worth of seconds.